# Rails/Devise: Storing a user list in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, models

I am trying to build a model to store event information and create a sign up list for it. What is the best way to associate a sign up list? Should I serialize a column and make it store like: user1, user2, user3 or should I create a new table. If I create a new table how would I relate it to this model? There are going to be multiple events with signups.

Currently I have this for the rest of the model:

```
rails generate model Event title:string description:string start:datetime end:datetime location:string numberofvolunteers:integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly standard data modelling problem and you'd typically want to model it as a many-to-many relationship. You'll need to generate an intermediate table to join events and users. Below I've added a couple of useful attributes you might want to track - whether the invite was accepted (RSVP'd) and whether they actually attended:

```
rails generate model Invite user_id:integer event_id:integer accepted:boolean attended:boolean
```

So then you have:

```
class Event
  has_many :invites
  has_many :users, through: :invites
end
```

And

```
class User
  has_many :invites
  has_many :events, through: :invites
end
```

And you can also get fancy by filtering on `accepted` and `attended` to create additional relationships if you want.

The solution here is very much "The Rails Way" and should probably be your default inclination when designing the database. However, your first suggestion of just storing a list of user IDs is possible too if you don't care to ever look up which events a user attended and you want to manually check the list is unique (so the same user isn't down twice).

Comment: Well I'm basically making a thing to sign up for a volunteering event, where a certain number of volunteers are needed. So this model doesn't work for me, but I get the general idea to apply it. I am using another model such that it has the name, email, startdatetime, enddatetime. I associated to the event model above with "belongs_to :event"

Comment: @ShravMehta That will work as long as users can only attend one event. It's possible, but that's a fairly unusual requirement especially if you want to track past attendance.

Comment: Oh, how can I apply this so that users can sign up for multiple events.

Comment: See my answer! You need a many-to-many relationship. You don't have to make it "Invites"; it could be "Attendances" for example, and maybe with fields like signed_up_at (if people requested to be there), attended_at, etc.

Comment: Ah, so I should say has_many for both the models. Thanks for the extra help!

Comment: Yes, but you can't just make the two tables and point them at each other with has_many. You'll need that third intermediate table.